# AngularJS Not Rendering Results in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I am trying out angularJS and I have the following in html, the problem I am facing here is 
it doesn't render any output in **Internet Explorer 8** after `<tr ng-repeat=`. What could the reason? I have attached screen shot for reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Employees</title>

<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular-resource.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/restangular.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>    
<body>
<div id="ng-app" ng-app ="emps">
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div ng-view></div>
            <!-- CACHE FILE: list.html -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="list.html">
<input type="text" ng-model="search" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
<thead>
 <tr>
 <th>Emp #</th>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Job</th>
 <th><a class="btn btn-success pull-right" href="#/new">
 <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>Add</a></th></tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="employee in employee.emp | filter:search | orderBy:'employee.ename'">
 <td>{{employee.empno}}</td>                
 <td>{{employee.ename}}</td>
 </td>
 <td>{{employee.job}}</td>
 <td>
 <a class="btn btn-warning" href="#/edit/{{employee.empno}}">
 <i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i></a>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </script>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Screen shot

[image]

Comment: did you read this : http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie ?

Comment: @ben75 Thanks for pointing to the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the issue by adding the following in `<head>`

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.2.6/json3.min.js">
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```